# How to update a table from a sub query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I may be going about this all wrong, but I need to update all customers' dealer_plate field with the license plate of the most recently entered vehicle for the customer if the customer is a dealer.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
UPDATE Customer C
SET    C.dealer_plate = (
       SELECT TOP 1 V.license_plate 
       FROM       Vehicle V 
       WHERE      V.fk_customer = C.pk_customer
       ORDER BY   V.pk_vehicle DESC)
WHERE  C.dealer = True
```

pk_vehicle is an AutoNumber field, so the highest value is the most recently entered vehicle.  The problem is that I'm being prompted to enter a parameter value for C.dealer_plate.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Try leaving out the `C.` in the outer query (it is definitely needed in the subquery).

Comment: What Gordon said, but you should only need to remove the `C.` in the `SET` clause.

Comment: I removed C. from the second line and from the last line, but I still get the same prompt.

Comment: @PeterKipe . . . That suggests that there is no column called `dealer_plate` in the table.  Check the spelling.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...I'm putting on my dunce cap right now...problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following (not tested).

Also I changed the way you get the license_plate.

```
UPDATE  Customer 
Set C.dealer_plate = license_plate
from Customer C
Inner join 
(
       SELECT fk_customer, pk_vehicle,  Max(license_plate) as license_plate
       FROM       Vehicle V 
       GROUP BY fk_customer, pk_vehicle 
) V on V.fk_customer = C.pk_customer
WHERE  C.dealer = True
```